# RoR - Not loading or requesting -any- assets in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, configuration

I'm brand new to Rails development and in a bit of a mess! **I've been given a codebase and none of the assets aren't being referenced in the HTML. No failed network requests, they simply aren't being included in the mark-up! They are present there when I attempt to access them directly using their URL though.**

As a comparison - my colleagues system ends up with around 30 or so requests and the end result is fully styled. However I have no styling and just the base mark-up.

I've done a fair amount of reading and checked my config, checked that I'm running in development mode and so on. I'm really stumped!

For what it's worth, I'm currently working in a cross-platform team environment where there are developers using Linux, Windows and Mac OS X. No one has these issues; and I'm pretty sure the other developer using Mac OS X has his set-up exactly the same as mine!

The source code was acquired from the same git repository as others, and it's definitely up to date. Below is the output from rails: note no errors.

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.6 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
        SECURITY WARNING: No secret option provided to Rack::Session::Cookie.
        This poses a security threat. It is strongly recommended that you
        provide a secret to prevent exploits that may be possible from crafted
        cookies. This will not be supported in future versions of Rack, and
        future versions will even invalidate your existing user cookies.

    Called from: /******************/abstract_store.rb:28:in `initialize'.
[2013-04-17 21:20:55] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2013-04-17 21:20:55] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-02-24) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]
[2013-04-17 21:20:55] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=22421 port=3000


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-17 21:21:05 +0100
Processing by AccountsController#home as HTML
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 6ms


Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-17 21:21:05 +0100
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (10.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 776ms (Views: 86.5ms | ActiveRecord: 647.5ms)


Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-17 21:21:06 +0100
Served asset /application.js - 304 Not Modified (1ms)


Started GET "/assets/application.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-17 21:21:06 +0100
Served asset /application.css - 304 Not Modified (1ms)
```

[image: Network Requests Screenshot]

**Note: The application.js just appears to have 5 `//=require` directives; and the application.css has mainly comments with a few simple rules - nowhere near what should be there.**

Comment: I had the same thing happen, I updated my rails version to the latest, run `bundle update` and reinstalled rvm. I'm not sure which of those three things fixed it, but after doing all of them assets were being included.

Comment: I just saw this funnily enough - I think it may have been on your question then. Unfortunately I can't find a way of updating rails on Mac OS X as everything says I'm to date - despite the security issues with my version..?!

Comment: How did you install Rails? Are you using RVM?

Comment: Just with gem, I do have RVM - I guess I could try and upgrade it using that actually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution is: install ruby version 1.9.3 and set this version as default. Restart your computer. Then install rails 3.2.6. Then clone a new repository for your source code (Do not reuse the one that is having error). Run bundle install.

Before this, I also tried to install ruby 1.9.2 with rvm but it does not work. Then I tried with ruby 1.9.3 and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem in a previous project. Personally I would try what everett1992 said because if that corrects the problem, it's probably best. But what I've used when that didn't work was the line

```
config.assets.prefix = "/assets_dev"
```

to my development.rb file.

Now, assets_dev is not a real directory, I never created it. But it forced rails to look there, and then when it doesn't see it, rails will load your assets from the default location as should happen in rails.

Like I said, it might work, but I'm sure its not the best way. I too work on OS X on cross platform projects with others, and I've yet to figure out why this sometimes happens.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using mac os x 10.6.8 and I have the same problem, and tried all the solutions above. Nothing work.
Including:
1> update gem
2> remove rvm, reinstall rvm, ruby, rails...
3> and make configuration as config(dot)assets(dot)prefix     =     "/assets_dev"

By the way, I've checked GoogleChrome console, and realize that, within application(dot)css, there is still statement as below:
    require_self
    require_tree.

Which mean these reference does not works at all.

The same things happen to application(dot)js

P/S: I'm using rails 3.2.6

Comment: This sounds identical to my situation unfortunately.

Comment: Hi Fergus Morrow, I added my solution to the answer. I hope that will help you also. Great day.